# upload image as offline using knockout javascript file in html5

Tags: image, html, upload, knockout.js, offline

I would like to upload image as offline(later based on network connectivity it will be synchronised) using knockout.js file.

at the moment, i can save textbox, checkbox data using knockout.js file but failed to store image files.

i am developing html5 based application.

thank you all in advance..

Answer (score 4):

Please try [**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/dmitry_zaets/rSArN/20/) that I've created.

Also see article that I've used : http://www.html5rocks.com/ru/tutorials/file/dndfiles/

Comment: @U10 you have answered mine ;)

Comment: Unbelievable, that solution has so few up-clicks. Very nice.